# Magento 1.9.2.1 problem with onestepcheckout in custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, onestepcheckout, ce-1.9.2.1

I've got a problem. I'm designing a theme on the basis of CoonCook theme.
The problem is that when I go to the onestep checkout the accordion won't load. only the HTML is shown and all steps are displayed. So I can't order anything.

Help me please

Comment: When I load the default theme it works like a charm...

Comment: the theme only has a cart and no onestep checkout. when I copied the onestep checkout to this theme from the base theme it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

if you ever get into a problem concerning above:
I was loading a js file in the footer of magento. that js file was calling the $ namespace for jQuery. As this namespace was taken by prototype.js a conflict was raised.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/
that will tell you how to disarm a problematic checkout and theme problem.